# Why doesn't flutter properly blur the whole background image?

Tags: flutter, dart, imagefilter

I'm trying to apply an `ImageFilter` on to my image but it only blurs part of it and fades off like this:
The Actual Image
[image: Actual Image]
Partly Blurred Image
[image: Partly blurred image]

As you can see, most of it is properly blurred but you can make out the bottom part.
How I'm blurring it:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: Image(image: AssetImage(config.wallpaper), fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        Container(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: config.blur['sigmaX'] ?? 50,
                  sigmaY: config.blur['sigmaY'] ?? 50),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                height: 1080,
                width: 1920,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dude I've added them

Comment: what you want to make exactly ??

Comment: I don't think I understand how much of a blur effect you desire. Can you share an example? However, I think the current image is also aptly blurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try stacking a translucent container above the image?

Something like this :

```
Stack(
  Image(/*your image*/),
  Container(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)),
),
```

You can adjust the color and opacity according to your need. You won't exactly be blurring the image but it will do a good work of hiding that image.